# React 2-stage render from Promise not rendering after first promise resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

My app sometimes receives a large volume of data it needs to parse and render. I want to parse the first couple of messages and render them to give the user something to work on while the rest of the messages parse in the background. The problem is, the first render in the image below does not result in a screen draw Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

[image]

```
parse(data, show) {
    if (data === null) {
        ...
    }
    else {
       if (data.length > 100) {
          let taste = [];
          taste.push(data.pop());
          taste.push(data.pop());

          console.log('start');
          const messagePromise = this.props.parser.parseMessages(taste);
          console.log('promise 1 created');

          const restPromise = messagePromise.then(result => {
            console.log('first chunk resolved, setting state!');
            if (this.state.messageDetail === null)
                this.setState({messageDetail: result[0]});
            this.setState({parsedMessages: this.state.parsedMessages.concat(result)});
            return this.props.parser.parseMessages(data);
           });
           console.log('promise 2 created');

           restPromise.then(result => {
              console.log('second chunk resolved, setting state!');
              if (this.state.messageDetail === null)
                 this.setState({messageDetail: result[0]});
              this.setState({parsedMessages: this.state.parsedMessages.concat(result)});
        });
        console.log('leaving parse');
    }
```

This method `parse` is passed as a prop to a child component who calls it when he has some messages to parse. There are 2 other child components that display the list of messages and the details of a selected message. These components have `parsedMessages` and `messageDetail` passed as props so when the state changes here in the parent the children rerender themselves.

Anyone seen an issue where a render doesn't result in a screen draw like this? I thought I was blocking somewhere but seeing the `render` in the log at `19:16:34.630` makes me think something else is going on.

I'm using latest React (`15.6.1`) and up-to-date browsers.

[image]

So looks like the page doesn't draw until the onClick returns. I thought that would have happened right away, after `promise 2` was created but before the `resolve` happened. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about how promises work.

```
        <RaisedButton onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} label="Parse" style={leftButtonStyle} secondary={true} disabled={!this.state.parseEnabled}/>

handleSubmit() {
    let messages = this.state.value.split('\n');
    this.props.parser(messages, true);
}
```

`handleSubmit()` should be done when `this.props.parser(...)` returns, the `onClick()` is bound to `handleSubmit()` and `this.props.parser()` is bound to the `parse()` method above which we can see from the console log exits at `19:16:34:619`

Comment: Is `setState ` async?

Comment: docs say: setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Comment: It's that bit about calls being batched that had me worried, but the `render` indicates that the `setState()` completed successfully and in fact triggered the render in the child with the dependent state.

Comment: Just confirmed that in fact `this.props.messages` (which is the prop associated with the parent's `this.state.parsedMessages`) contains 2 messages in the first render.

Answer (score 0):

bloodyowl in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7678 solved the issue. Still not sure why a promise is not sufficient (maybe because it's being transpiled?) but doing the initial partial `render()` and then in `componentDidUpdate()` -- doesn't work if you do it in the `setState()` callback -- wrapping the stage 2 processing in a `setTimeout(doParsing, 0)` breaks the chain so to speak and allows the initial render to paint.